# Design flaw in the number/items per page selector

Tags: discussion, bug, feature-request, design, status-reproduced

I've noticed Ask Different's CSS is much less legible than other Stack Exchange sites:

Pretty selector:

[image: 1]

Not pretty selector:

[image: 2]

<sup>(produced by hovering over a choice)</sup>

Could we change it so that the text is darker than the grey circle shown upon hover?

**Edit:** Here I've used Chrome's dev tools to change

```
.page-sizer a.page-numbers {
    color:#ccc;
}
```

To:

```
.page-sizer a.page-numbers {
    color:rgb(111,111,111);
}
```

Here's the results:

**Before:**

[image] [image]

**After:**

[image][image]

Not perfect, but it gives @Jin something to work off of.

Comment: Good eye! I'll bet @jin and company could patch that up once they reproduce it / see this request.

Comment: Almost always, but the designers probably get too many to check them all…

Comment: @bmike How's my new design look?

Comment: I like it.. Had I write access and it didn't break something else, I'd ship your change.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to show how the current design looks on Safari Version 6.0.5 (8536.30.1):

[image: Meta Hover looks fine to me]

[image: Site hover is very hard to use]

My cursor at the time was the hand outline with a pointing finger and it was hovering over the 50 in both cases. It looks like the meta design is very close to your proposed coloring already.